# Shiny Dashboard mini sidebar displays text

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I am using Shiny DashboardPlus and I want the sidebar-mini to display only icons. The problem is that text appears also.

Same issue with shiny dashboard also.

The code for creating the sidebar menu below:

```
sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("DASHBOARD1", tabName = "Spectrum", icon = icon("table")
        ), #menuItem
        menuItem("DASHBOARD2", tabName = "LTE", icon = icon("mobile-alt"))        
      )),
```

See it here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be version issue as it all works fine for me:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
      rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("DASHBOARD1", tabName = "Spectrum", icon = icon("table")
        ), #menuItem
        menuItem("DASHBOARD2", tabName = "LTE", icon = icon("mobile-alt"))        
      )),
    body = dashboardBody(),
    title = "TEST"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Here is the sample session Info:

> R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
>
> shiny_1.2.0
>
> shinydashboard_0.7.1
>
> shinydashboardPlus_0.6.0.9000

[image]

Comment: I updated everything and still same problem in my PC (windows 7, 32bit). Tried at a different PC, also windows 7 and works properly. Browsers also updated. Any thoughts?